# Django Migration Error - NodeNotFoundError

Tags: django, django-migrations

Django verstion 1.8

Trying to migrate a newly added app in my project. Here is the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 63, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 318, in build_graph
    _reraise_missing_dependency(migration, parent, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 288, in _reraise_missing_dependency
    raise exc
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration weather.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'machines', u'0006_auto_20150921_1327')
```

I have not found much helpful information in researching this. Syntax is correct in all models. Here is what doesn't make sense: this is just a copy of a working project. So it works on one computer, but not here. The machines model it's referencing has already been created and is working. Any ideas???

Comment: Does the required migration file `machines/migrations/0006_auto_20150921_1327.py` exist?

Comment: I don't think it does... I was using an older version of Django and never had to create migrations files before, so I don't know if this is "new" or not. It is to me anyhow... :) Researching it now and came across the same thing - having to create a migration file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting the error because the migration you are trying to run, `weather.0001_initial`, depends on a migration `machines.0006_auto_20150921_1327` which does not exist.

If you can't find the missing migration file, you'll have to delete and recreate the migrations for the `weather` app, so that they don't depend on the missing migration.

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do. A migration directory had been created. So I deleted it and ran the migration. The new migration was able to be processed and everything works well now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are missing the

```
__init__.py
```

file in your migrations folder.

For me, it worked after adding this file.