# i ran "Django manage.py runserver" and i get a "NodeNotFoundError"

Tags: django, django-manage.py

newbie to python so i followed "Django by example" after i finished the blog project i committed to GitHub repository master. Only for me to clone the project later and [image: run "Django manage.py runserver" and i get a "NodeNotFoundError".]

Comment: clear the migration files and remigrate.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: easy solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33676462/8243936)

Comment: The failing migration is `auth.0013_user_following`?? But there is no such migration in the `django.contrib.auth` app (not even in the development version of Django), how do you end up with this error? Did you try to modify the package's code locally?